# pyqt : Convert numpy array to QImage

Tags: python, qt, numpy, pyqt, easy-install

I need to convert a numpy array to a QtGui.QImage. But I don't know how to do that. I've find this : http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/qimage2ndarray/ but when I try to install this I get an error :

```
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs$ easy_install
error: No urls, filenames, or requirements specified (see --help)
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs$ easy_install qimage2ndarraySearching for qimage2ndarray
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/qimage2ndarray/
Reading http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/qimage2ndarray
Reading http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/qimage2ndarray/dist
Best match: qimage2ndarray 1.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/q/qimage2ndarray/qimage2ndarray-1.0.zip#md5=5e79e1b45b87aa8e18490162adcce8e4
Processing qimage2ndarray-1.0.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-aWUHHO/qimage2ndarray-1.0/setup.cfg
Running qimage2ndarray-1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-aWUHHO/qimage2ndarray-1.0/egg-dist-tmp-SGavOY
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/.local/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.27', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1915, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1896, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1919, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 350, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 590, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 620, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 814, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1094, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1080, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 30, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 78, in run
    return func()
  File "/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 32, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> exit

#PythonPath
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> pp(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/michael/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']


michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:/lib$ python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__file__"
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc
```

When I try to fix error like ekhumoro said :

```
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
[sudo] password for michael: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-setuptools is already the newest version.
python-setuptools set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  language-pack-zh-hans language-pack-kde-zh-hans kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-zhcn
  language-pack-zh-hans-base language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs$ /usr/bin/easy_install --user qimage2ndarray
Searching for qimage2ndarray
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/qimage2ndarray/
Reading http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/qimage2ndarray
Reading http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/qimage2ndarray/dist
Best match: qimage2ndarray 1.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/q/qimage2ndarray/qimage2ndarray-1.0.zip#md5=5e79e1b45b87aa8e18490162adcce8e4
Processing qimage2ndarray-1.0.zip
Running qimage2ndarray-1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-WlOZgX/qimage2ndarray-1.0/egg-dist-tmp-YImfzM
sip: Deprecation warning: qimageview.sip:2: %Module version number should be specified using the 'version' argument
sip: Unable to find file "QtGui/QtGuimod.sip"
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/sip' failed with exit status 1
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs$ sudo /usr/bin/easy_install qimage2ndarray
Searching for qimage2ndarray
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/qimage2ndarray/
Reading http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/qimage2ndarray
Reading http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/software/qimage2ndarray/dist
Best match: qimage2ndarray 1.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/q/qimage2ndarray/qimage2ndarray-1.0.zip#md5=5e79e1b45b87aa8e18490162adcce8e4
Processing qimage2ndarray-1.0.zip
Running qimage2ndarray-1.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-cVFRpr/qimage2ndarray-1.0/egg-dist-tmp-Dll6jK
sip: Deprecation warning: qimageview.sip:2: %Module version number should be specified using the 'version' argument
sip: Unable to find file "QtGui/QtGuimod.sip"
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/sip' failed with exit status 1
michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:~/rubyWorkSpace/pymcs$
```

I don't understand this error because obviously import numpy works...

If anyone knows an other way to convert numpy array to QImage it could be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have numpy in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, or elsewhere? If you can import NumPy normally, what does a `python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__file__"` tell you?

Comment: michael@michael-laptop-ubuntu:/lib$ python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__file__"
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc

Comment: So NumPy is installed in the system default location while you're trying to install your package in your `.local`. At this point, the system cannot find NumPy. What does your `PYTHONPATH` looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback shows that you are trying to install the package using the  `easy_install` installed under the [`USER_BASE`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE) directory (`~/.local/bin/easy_install`).

This is in turn using the python installed under `/opt/ActivePython-2.7`, which presumably doesn't have the `numpy` package installed.

However, it appears that your system python (`/usr/lib/python2.7`), *does* have the `numpy` package installed.

So to fix the error, first install the ubuntu package which includes `easy_install`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

And then do either:

```
/usr/bin/easy_install --user qimage2ndarray
```

to install `qimage2ndarray` to your [`USER_SITE`](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) directory, or:

```
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install qimage2ndarray
```

to install it so that it is available system-wide.

Comment: Thank you for this high quality answer, however I get some error when I try to apply your fix, see the initial edit post.

Comment: @MichaelSusplugas. It looks like you also need to install the ubuntu `python-qt4-dev` package (which includes the missing `QtGui/QtGuimod.sip` file).

Comment: well, now I can import qimage2ndarray. Thank you ekhumoro =)